# Java Calendar getTimeInMillis() Returning the Same Time

Tags: java, milliseconds, java.util.calendar

I have a piece of code like this:

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    long startTime = c.getTimeInMillis();

    while (x < 10000000) {//check all the integers from 1 to 10000000 to
                          //to see if they're prime or not}

    long endTime = c.getTimeInMillis();
    long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
```

The loop runs 10 million times so surely `startTime` and `endTime` would contain different values.

However `totalTime` is always equal to 0.

Why does `startTime` and `endTime` contain the same value?

Any help would be appreciateed =)

Comment: `Calendar`, despite the name, holds just one instant in time. it is not a clock. You could use `System.currentTimeMillis()` or `System.nanoTime()`

Comment: or a bit newer , the `Instant` class: `var start = Instant.now(); ... var end = Instant.now(); var duration = Duration between(start, end);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
Duration.between(       // Represent a span-of-time as a count of nanoseconds, to be calculated as hours-minutes-seconds.
    then ,              // Earlier in your code, capture the previous current moment: `Instant then = Instant.now() ;`
    Instant.now()       // Capture the current moment. 
)                       // Returns a `Duration` object, our elapsed time.
.toNanos()              // Get the total number of nanoseconds in the entire span-of-time. Returns a `long`.
```

## Capturing current moment

Your code is capturing the current moment, a snapshot, frozen. The resulting object is *not* updated. That is what the phrase “a specific instant in time” means in the class JavaDoc.

To track elapsed time, you must capture the current moment *twice*, resulting in two separate objects.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The `Calendar` class is terrible, and was supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310. Specifically, `ZonedDateTime` replaces `GregorianCalendar`, the usual implementation of `Calendar`.

## `Instant`

The modern approach to tracking the current moment uses the `Instant` class. An `Instant` represents a moment in UTC.

```
Instant start = Instant.now() ;
…  // Do some stuff.
Instant stop = Instant.now() ;
```

## Resolution

In Java 9 and later, the current moment is captured with a resolution of microseconds (6 decimal digits of fractional second). In Java 8, an Instant the older implementation of `Clock` is limited to capturing the current moment in milliseconds (3 decimal digits). In all versions of Java, the `Instant` class has the capacity to represent a moment in nanoseconds (9 decimal digits). But conventional computer clocks cannot accurately track time so finely.

## `Duration`

Calculate elapsed time as a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) object.

```
Duration duration = Duration.between( start , stop ) ;  // Represents a span of time in terms of hours-minutes-seconds.
long nanoseconds = duration.toNanos() ;                 // Converts this duration to the total length in nanoseconds expressed as a long.
```

## `System.nanoTime`

For microbenchmarking, you may want to use [`System.nanoTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()). That method captures the current moment as a number of nanoseconds since some arbitrary starting point. Beware: This value returned does *not* represent the current moment according to any clock or calendar. But it is useful for tracking elapsed time at a resolution possibly finer than `Instant`.

```
long start = System.nanoTime() ;  // Some arbitrarily defined count of nanoseconds. *NOT* the current time/date by any clock/calendar. 
…  // Do some stuff.
long stop = System.nanoTime() ;
long nanoseconds = ( stop - start ) ;
```

### JEP 230: Microbenchmark Suite

For serious benchmarking, check out the newly built-in benchmarking framework added to Java 12 and later, based on [JMH](https://openjdk.org/projects/code-tools/jmh/). See [JEP 230: Microbenchmark Suite](https://openjdk.org/jeps/230).